# Scipy's normaltest Function Seems Inaccurate

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, normal-distribution

Using `scipy.stats.norm` to generate a random sample, then running that through `scipy.stats.normaltest` produces wildly varying outputs:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, normaltest

normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (0.10435743048081543, 0.94915922246569517)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (0.57583529133190114, 0.74982334089826597)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (0.074086867327589984, 0.96363428027274967)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (2.0817923824843461, 0.35313806086602029)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (0.25177398640139054, 0.88171448088503002)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (2.5213062252950227, 0.2834688289515595)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (2.0550957310741165, 0.35788346385342579)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (4.5722298301301869, 0.10166065590209576)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (3.0060164141422421, 0.22245994699827343)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (1.8870291791486471, 0.38925734860089078)
normaltest(norm.rvs(size=1000))
# (0.24931060262844901, 0.88280115054104014)
```

Only one of these has a p-value < 0.05. This seems really broken. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`normaltest` returns a 2-tuple. The first value is a chi-square statistic, the second value is the p-value.

So in your example above, there are actually no p-values < 0.05.

The docstring for `normaltest` [may be incorrect](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1479); My claim is corrobated by looking at the source code (/usr/share/pyshared/scipy/stats/stats.py):

```
def normaltest(a, axis=0):
    a, axis = _chk_asarray(a, axis)
    s,p = skewtest(a,axis)
    k,p = kurtosistest(a,axis)
    k2 = s*s + k*k
    return k2, chisqprob(k2,2)
```

(Edit: Note the docstring [is correct](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html#scipy.stats.normaltest) as of the latest version of `scipy.stats`.)

---

It is not abnormal at all!

A p-value < 0.05 should happen about 5% of the time.
Try running that command 1000 times and see if it is true:

```
In [67]: import scipy.stats as stats

In [69]: pvals = [stats.normaltest(stats.norm.rvs(size=1000))[1] for i in range(1000)]

In [71]: sum([1 for p in pvals if p < 0.05])/1000.0
Out[71]: 0.053
```

Comment: :) I had two problems: 1) I was reading the p-value output backwards and 2) it's been way too long since I've taken stats.